# Why am I getting expression must have pointer to class type in c++?

Tags: c++

Hey I am trying compare values of vector that store class objects to another vector of same class.
I have class in seperate .h file containing following

```
class Student{
std::string ID;
std::string Name;
std::vector<std::string> FriendsIDs
Student(std::string ID, std::string Name, std::vector<std::string> FriendsIDs)
~Student(){}
};
```

and the class goes so on...
the values I stored in objects are like

```
std::vector<Student* > List_Students = { {"123", "Sam", {"234", "435"}}, {"234", "Shane", {"435"}}, {"435", "Mitch", {"123"}}};
```

and so on and on the list goes (I read it from file, those are just few for testing), I want to compare the FriendsIDs with ID and if it matches it should print friends name with thier IDs.
Expected  output:

```
123, sam, 234(shane), 435(mitch)
234, shane, 435(mitch)
```

etc
I used the bottom code that i inherit from stackoverflow, which was working until i put class into seperate .h file. I get error at last line of code (iter->Name), the error read "expression must have pointer to class type". My guess is that iter doesn't know what Name is, if so how do I point or fix this issue please. thank you

```
  for (Student* s : List_Students)
            {
                for (string& f : s->FriendsID)
                {
                    auto iter = find_if(List_Students.begin(), List_Students.end(), [&](Student* sf) { return sf->ID == f; });
                    if (iter != List_Students.end())
                    {
                        cout << " ( " << iter->Name << " ) " << "\n";
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Why do you have `std::vector<Student* >` instead of `std::vector<Student>`?

Comment: the error message should tell you in which line and column the error is. Please include it in the question

Comment: That initialization of `List_Students` won't work. When posting code please take care to show us a proper [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List_Students` is a vector of `Student*`, so `iter` "points at" `Student*`. Therefore you have to do "dereferencing" two times to access corresponding `Student`.

Therefore, you should use `(*iter)->Name` (or `(**iter).Name`) instead of `iter->Name`.

Comment: While I agree, `std::vector<Student* > List_Students = { {"123", "Sam", {"234", "435"}}, {"234", "Shane", {"435"}}, {"435", "Mitch", {"123"}}};` in the Q also can't compile, so something seems off.